The terminal prints out RAM addresses instead of the actual question text Python
I have my classes and data in different files and I hold my data as a dictionary.
class QuizBrain:
def __init__(self, question_list):
    self.question_number = 0
    self.question_list = question_list
    self.score = 0

def still_has_questions(self):
    return self.question_number < len(self.question_list)

def next_question(self):
    current_question = self.question_list[self.question_number]
    self.question_number += 1
    user_answer = input(f"{self.question_number}: {current_question} (True/False): ")

def check_answer(self, user_answer, correct_answer):
    if user_answer.lower() == correct_answer.lower():
        self.score += 1
        print("You got it right!")
    else:
        print("That's wrong")
    print(f"The correct answer was: {correct_answer}")
    print(f"Your current score is {self.score}/{self.question_number}")
    print("\n")

class Question:
def __init__(self, text, answer):
    self.text = text
    self.answer = answer

I'm watching a code tutorial, and they have no problem running this code. When I run the code, I get the ram addresses:
1: <question_model.Question object at 0x7b7af8a0bb60> (True/False): True
2: <question_model.Question object at 0x7b7af8a0bef0> (True/False): False
3: <question_model.Question object at 0x7b7af8a0bf50> (True/False): True
4: <question_model.Question object at 0x7b7af8a0bf80> (True/False): True
5: <question_model.Question object at 0x7b7af8a0bfb0> (True/False): 

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm not very experienced.
This is my main.py
from data import question_data
from question_model import Question
from quiz_brain import QuizBrain

question_bank = []
for question in question_data:
    question_text = question["text"]
    question_answer = question["answer"]
    new_question = Question(question_text, question_answer)
    question_bank.append(new_question)

quiz = QuizBrain(question_bank)

while quiz.still_has_questions():
    quiz.next_question()

print("You've completed the quiz!")
print(f"Your final score was: {quiz.score}/{quiz.question_number}")


current_question is a Question object. that's the default way a user-defined object will be represented as a string. you probably want to access one if the attributes of that question object.

You are printing the object, instead of the question field.
Option 1:
In your QuizBrain class, update next_question method to print current_question.text instead of current_question:
def next_question(self):
    current_question = self.question_list[self.question_number]
    self.question_number += 1
    user_answer = input(f"{self.question_number}: {current_question.text} (True/False): ") # Update this line

Option 2:
Another option would be to add __str__ method to the Question class:
def __str__(self):
     return self.text

With this option, anytime you try to print a Question object, it will automatically call __str__ and output Question.text instead of what you are seeing now.
